# How to draw scatter plot with errorbars from huge lists of data in a fast way?

Tags: plotting

I want to make a scatter plot using two huge lists that give the $x$ and $y$ coordinates of the points. To each $(x,y)$ point I want to add a symmetric errorbar (I have anothe list with the errors) in the $y$ direction.

I know the solution to this problem following the instructions given in [this](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ErrorBarPlots/ref/ErrorBar.html) link. The problem is that the fact that my lists are huge makes doing this by hand tedious.

Is there a way to implement this method in a more effective way rather than introducing the command suggested in the link I have provided by hand for all points?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given that you have three lists with data, one for the x coordinates, one for the y coordinates and one for the error bar, this is pretty easy. We just have to generate a new list where every element is picked from corresponding positions of the respective lists.

This combined list is then turned into the `{{x, y}, ErrorBar[error]}` triplet required by `ErrorListPlot`.

```
Needs["ErrorBarPlots`"]

x = {1, 2, 3, 4};
y = {2, 4, 6, 8};
e = {1, 2, 3, 4}/5;

ErrorListPlot[{{#1, #2}, ErrorBar[#3]} & @@@ Transpose[{x, y, e}]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: and how could I use this method to make a plot with two data sets, x1,y1,e1 and x2,y2,e3?

Comment: ErrorListPlot[{ {{#1, #2}, ErrorBar[#3]} & @@@ Transpose[{x1, y1, e1}], {{#1, #2}, ErrorBar[#3]} & @@@ Transpose[{x2, y2, e3}]]